# Path to static files in Django CMS admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-cms

I'm having an issue with some administrative icons being used in a Django CMS I have deployed for one of my clients. As you can see from the attached image, the path to the static folder where the images are stored is wrong and therefore doesn't render the icons. It's missing the static part of the URL. Can anyone provide any pointers on this?

Many thanks in advance for any assistance people may be able to provide on this

[image: Visual representation of error]

Comment: This is server config related, and the answer you've got assumes you're using nginx. What is your server running?

Answer (score 0):

In production go to,

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/django**

Remove or comment these lines

```
#location /static/admin {
#   alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
#}
```

You can have a look on [my website for this.](https://www.kodefork.com/questions/40/django-admin-panel-missing-static-files-on-digitalocean-server-using-nginx/)

Comment: The link you provide is a dead link?

Comment: No, The link is working, [click here](https://www.kodefork.com/questions/34/django-admin-panel-missing-static-files-on-digitalocean-server-using-nginx/)

Comment: I have not as of yet, my limitations of Django are not to that standard, I usually have a developer do this for me but he is becoming increasingly difficult to get hold of. I have server access via FTP, that's as far as my skillset goes

Comment: Ask him to follow the solution and it should work fine.

Comment: The link is now working yes, I shall pass on the comment to my developer and ask him to action this for me. As mentioned, this is past my abilities to action this, I wouldn't know how to access production.